# Selecting rows which are not linked to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'messages', which contains the columns `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `message` (the text of the message) and `readbyrecipient` (a flag to indicate whether the message was read by the person to whom it was sent.

I am implementing the option to block users, so have added a table called `block` with columns `blocker_id` (the user who did the blocking) and `blockee_id` (the user who was blocked). All of the `*_id` columns link to my `users` table.

I am trying to get all unread messages which are not sent from users which were blocked by the recipient. Here's the query I have been working with:

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM 
    messages A,
    block B 
WHERE 
    A.recipient_id = 18
    AND A.readbyrecipient = 0
    AND NOT (
                B.blocker_id = A.recipient_id
                AND
                B.blockee_id = A.sender_id
            )
```

This returns no rows, even though I know the user id specified in A.recipient_id refers to a user who has one unread message from a user whom they have not blocked. I tried removing the `AND NOT` clause in the query, but it still returned zero rows until I removed `block B` from the SELECT part of the query, so I'm not sure whether the problem is with the `WHERE` clause or the `SELECT` clause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one of these:

1) LEFT JOIN. Please don't use the old crummy JOIN syntax you use, as it does not allow LEFT JOINs and is much harder to read.

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM 
    messages A
    LEFT JOIN block B ON 
        (B.blocker_id = A.recipient_id AND B.blockee_id = A.sender_id)
WHERE 
    A.recipient_id = 18
    AND B.blocker_id IS NULL
```

Note "B.blocker_id IS NULL" means "LEFT JOIN did not find rows according to JOIN criteria" which is what you want here. Read up on LEFT OUTER JOIN.

2) Good old NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM messages A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM block 
    WHERE B.blocker_id = A.recipient_id AND B.blockee_id = A.sender_id
)
WHERE A.recipient_id = 18
```

3) NOT IN does not apply here since we got 2 columns to test.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I still haven't got my head around LEFT JOIN, but the syntax you provided made perfect sense to me. This works perfectly. The SQL runs in the background and updates a notification indicator, and if I repeatedly block and unblock the user who sent the message I can see the value changing accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! Find a tutorial on join types, you'll need them ;)

Comment: I did just Google it and started reading one, but having had a couple of beers it made my brain hurt. I'll try again tomorrow ;)

Comment: Shouldn't the AND in the SELECT in the where not exists be OR? Unless the blacker is the one blocked and the one blocked, that will never be true.

Comment: Hmm, if "blocker_id" is the recipient who doesn't want spam, then each recipient should be able to define their own list of "blockee_id" blocked senders... If you use OR, then if just one user blocks one "blockee_id", then this blockee_id will no longer be able to send messages to anyone, since the OR will always return TRUE...

Comment: peufeu is correct. In this scenario it must be AND to ensure it checks for matches where the currently logged in user is checked as both the recipient of the message and the blocker, and the sender of the message is matched as the blockee

Comment: ... or rather, it should *not* match on those criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the records that do not have a matching record by using a left join and then in the where clause, specifying that a field in that table must be null. True only for records that didn't have a match.

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM `messages` A
LEFT JOIN `BLOCK` B
ON B.`blockee_id` = a.`sender_id` OR B.`blockee_id` = a.`recipient_id`
WHERE b.`blockee_id` is NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have you a +1, but accepted a different answer only because the SQL syntax matched my particular scenario slightly better and it also gave other options. Thanks again though for taking the time to respond.